# How do I rust proof a garage door track?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

I have a couple of questions about how to do this:

1. Is it safe to cut the bottom 1-1.5 inches off the track so that it's not in direct contact with the concrete of the garage?  I often get standing water during the winter up against the garage door and this would prevent the track from sitting in it.
2. Would regular rust proofing spray paint be adequate for this kind of use?  I don't believe the portion I'm cleaning is actually in contact with the roller so it shouldn't get too much rubbing from the rollers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carefully determine where the wheels of the bottom of your door stop being used.  Any point below the bottom of the wheels when the door is completely down should be safe to remove.  The track shouldn't have to go all the way to the ground.

I would not paint the track, for fear that it will interfere with smooth motion.  If anything I'd use grease to lube up the track, which will put a protective surface on the inside of the track where you need it and improve performance (less resistance).

Rust on the outside of the track won't matter except aesthetically.

Comment: just ensure that the section that you remove does not have the wall anchors, also, it is highly probable that the track is galvanized, so when you cut. you will destroy the integrity of the zink... (i.e. it will rust on the end)... you will have to touch up the with rust inhibitor and a coat of enamel ( as Greebo says, make sure the area painted does not contact the area where the wheel is at play)

Comment: I should've clarified, I was only going to paint the very bottom portion that is closest to the floor, nothing actually in the area that the roller travels on.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo, what grease or lube would you recommend?

Comment: Any standard engine/machine grease, very VERY lightly applied, should suffice.  Nothing liquid, it'll just run off.